# Write zip to Blob storage Azure

Tags: python, azure-blob-storage, azure-sdk-python

I'm trying to zip files present in container 'input' and move them to container 'output'.
I'm using python SDK

```
# connection to blob storage via Azure Python SDK
connection_string = "myConnectionString"

blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connection_string)

# get container client
input_container = blob_service_client.get_container_client(container="input")

# filename
filename = "document_to_zip.pdf"

# init zip object
zip_filename = "document_zipped.zip"
zip_object = ZipFile(zip_filename, "w")

data = input_container.download_blob(filename).readall()
zip_object.write(data)

# upload blob to results container as .zip file
results_blob = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container="output",blob=zip_filename)
results_blob.upload_blob(zip_object, overwrite=True)
```

Get the following error :
Exception: ValueError: stat: embedded null character in path.
More general question : do you think my approach is fine regarding ziping and moving blob from one container to another ?

Thanks

Comment: Could you please elaborate your question. You are trying to move zip file from input to output containers or you need to convert pdf file to zip file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, this error occurs when path contains '/' or ' \' in it. Meanwhile I could able to resolve it by removing the `zip_object.write(data)` line. Also keep in mind that the above-mentioned code works only for a single file in input container with an unsupported content which throws an error when downloaded.

The below code works but gives error when downloaded

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient
from zipfile import ZipFile

# connection to blob storage via Azure Python SDK
connection_string = "<YOUR_CONNECTION_STRING>"

blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connection_string)

# get container client
input_container = blob_service_client.get_container_client(container="input")

# filename
filename = "document_to_zip.pdf"

# init zip object
zip_filename = "document_zipped.zip"
zip_object = ZipFile(zip_filename, "w")

data = input_container.download_blob(filename).readall()

# upload blob to results container as .zip file
results_blob = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container="output",blob=zip_filename)
results_blob.upload_blob(zip_object, overwrite=True)
```

***RESULTS:***

[image]

---

Meanwhile you can save a group of files by looping inside the input container and zip them inside output container.

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient
from zipfile import ZipFile

connection_string = "<Your_CONNECTION_STRING>"

blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connection_string)

input_container = blob_service_client.get_container_client(container="input")

generator = input_container.list_blobs()
for blob in generator:    
    data = input_container.download_blob(blob.name).readall()
    results_blob = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container="output"+"/"+"ZipFolder.zip",blob=blob.name)
    results_blob.upload_blob(data, overwrite=True)
```

***RESULTS:***

[image]

[image]